# Инициализация и проверка записи в бд. Python, sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

Есть скрипт, в нем три функции. Первая инициализирует бд, вторая вставляет запись в бд, третья проверяет есть ли запись в бд.

В теории все должно работать так. Но на практике функция проверки записей возвращает значение из бд только со второго запуска.

Вот код:

```py
import os
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join('test_db.db'))
cursor = conn.cursor()


def init_db():
    with open('create_test_db.sql', 'r') as f:
        sql = f.read()
    cursor.executescript(sql)
    conn.commit()
    print('bd is init')


def test_query():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test_table("
                        "t1)"
                        "VALUES("
                        "100)")
    conn.commit()
    fetch = cursor.fetchone()
    print(fetch)  # Всегда None. Почему?


def test_check():
    info = cursor.execute("SELECT t1 FROM test_table;")
    fetch = info.fetchone()
    if info.fetchone() is None:
        print('empty')  # Здесь в первый запуск None. Только повторный запрос возвращает значение.
    else:
        print(fetch)


init_db()
test_query()
test_check()
```

В sql скрипте вот такая запись:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table(
    date DATA DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    t1 INT DEFAULT 0,
    t2 INT DEFAULT 0,
    t3 INT DEFAULT 0
);
```

Основной вопрос такой: почему `test_check()` возвращает None в первый запуск. Ведь `test_query()` вносит данные в табличку до запроса информации (хотя `fethc` все-равно всегда отдает `None`, что тоже весьма интересно).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в `test_check` вы вызываете `fetchone()` два раза и первый результат (т.е. первую запись) игнорируете. По-этому, работает только со второго раза, т.е. когда вставится вторая запись. Измените на:

```
def test_check():
    info = cursor.execute("SELECT t1 FROM test_table;")
    fetch = info.fetchone()
    if fetch is None:
        print('empty')  # Здесь в первый запуск None. Только повторный запрос возвращает значение.
    else:
        print(fetch)
```

Ну а в `test_query` значение всегда `None` потому, что вы выполнили запрос `INSERT`, который не возвращает записей, потому `fetchone` возвращает `None`.

Comment: Омг, даже стыдно стало за такую невнимательность. Спасибо огромное.

INSERT ничего не возвращает, это я уяснил, а fetchone работает только при выполнении SELECT?

Comment: `fetchone` работает, если запрос возвращает результат (resultset). `select` возвращает всегда, но в некоторых БД и `INSERT`/`UPDATE` тоже [могут возвращать](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html) данные.